# Как сделать отображение текста поверх картинки?

Tags: html, css

```css
.recipe {
  margin-top: 86px;
  height: 458px;
  margin-left: 157px;
  margin-right: 157px;
  background-image: url(../images/dish_photo.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe">
  <div class="recipe_text">
    <a>Bananas Foster Ice Cream Cake</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно просто добавить свойство `display` и соответствующее выравнивание:

```css
.recipe {
  margin-top: 86px;
  height: 458px;
  margin-left: 157px;
  margin-right: 157px;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBFDX.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* добавлено */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #444;
  font: bold 26px/1em sans-serif;
}

.recipe_text {
  text-align: center;
  transform: scaleY(3);
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px white, 0 0 3px white, 0 0 6px white;
}
```

```html
<div class="recipe">
  <div class="recipe_text">
    <a>Bananas Foster Ice Cream Cake</a>
  </div>
</div>
```